# Pass user object to model life cycle event in Sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I'm interested if anyone had managed to pass current logged in user to lifecycle events

I would like to pass the user to the lifecycle events function to keep track of the user making the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a clean way to do this. Even if you don't mind digging into (and modifying) the framework code, I think you'd have to make a few modifications in a few places:

1 - You'd have to override `Model.create` to accept a `req` parameter (or something else you can use to get the logged in user).

2 - You'd have to make sure that all uses in the code (yours AND the sails library's) of `Model.create` pass in the required parameter. In particular...

3 - You'd have to modify the default action caught by `POST /create/[modelname]` so that it passed in the appropriate parameters to `Model.create`

---

Given that that is a lot of steps (and I likely missed some), I'd recommend another approach:

1 - Disable the REST create route from your `/config/blueprints.js` file.

2 - Funnel all model creation through a custom method. (Could be a directly exposed controller method, or something in `/api/services`, or in the model itself). Make sure the method gets access to the logged in user, attach it as data to the model, THEN call the default Model.create from within your custom method.

Comment: I'm talking about afterCreate and afterUpdate LifeCycle events. any ideas on how to add to that functions the req?

Comment: I think similar logic could apply to `afterCreate` even though I was talking about create above (you would just do your custom stuff *after* calling `Model.create` from your custom method. As for update, I'm afraid it would just be repeating the process.

Comment: OK... found a way. what do you think about setting the sails.user to the user?
should it work with global variable `sails` and async running the server?

Comment: Ok global is not an option, because if the async concurrency.
I dont want to change a core code. and dont want to create another function just to pass in a user.
so the last resort is to just add to all models `usersModified: `

Comment: Yes, the "quick and dirty" way is to just pass in the extra property you want "modified by" or whatever. As you say, global variables will not work, because many logged in users could be doing these actions at once.